# Object of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag could not be converted to string - Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, eloquent, wildcard, where-clause

i want to run the query `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE author = 'mubeen' && name LIKE '%query%'"`
But i am not getting results successfully .getting this error

> Object of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag could
>   not be converted to string.

I search on google applied different query strategies to get data but nothing gain.

Here is My controller

**usersController.php**

```
public function searchingResults(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->query;

    $users  = User::where([
      ['author', 'mubeen'],
      ['name' ,'LIKE','%'.$query.'%'],
    ])->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(4);   

    $roles  = Role::where(
        'author' , 'superAdmin'
    )->get();

    return view('BackEnd.users.searchResults',compact('users','query'));
}
```

if i put **"%$query%"** i get no error but also getting no results even if i put same name as with db table..please help me i am asking question here after wasting my 4-5 hours in other places.

Thanks

[This is my db table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaYVg.png)

Comment: may we get a  screenshot of your db itself where the tables are

Comment: @MubeenAli show `$query`  variable value.

Comment: `Object of class ... could not be converted to string.` as You understand that the query You're passing is not a string. So You've to find out how to get string from query.  Fix to `$query = $request->input('query');`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$users = User::where('author', 'mubeen')
               ->where('name' ,'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
               ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(4);
```

make sure name space of Requset is `Illuminate\Http\Request;`

check your form make sure it's a post method

check the name of the input field (query) in your form

Comment: is query an input ? try dd($request->query)

Comment: if i dd($request->query) i am getting  #parameters []

Comment: 1.check your form make sure it's a post method to the 
2.check the name of the input field

Comment: i am including this form into my view .becasue i need the search functionlity on each page ...Will it may be a problem

Comment: i checked my form and name attribute again and again it is same as expected!

Comment: dd($request->query) and send us a screenshort of your tables in the db

Comment: i have attached the db table structure in the post above please see.

Comment: i see it there is no problem with db

Comment: do note you dont have a field author in the db sent

Comment: do note you dont have a field author in the db sent

Comment: only name email blocked status

Comment: Object of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag could not be converted to string.

the is no problem with db just check the request object

Comment: i have the Author filed in my table in screenshot it is not showing

Comment: @AhmadElkenany please help me the problem is with request if i dd($request->query) i am getting ParameterBag {#63 ▼
  #parameters: []
}

Comment: --Illuminate\Http\Request is the request object under this name space--

1.check your form make sure it's a post method
2.check the name of the input field

Comment: @MubeenAli check answer

Comment: @MubeenAli your answer just like i said. changing the name off the attribute

Answer (score 0):

You tried this one? :

```
$users = User::where('author', 'mubeen')
           ->where('name' ,'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')
           ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
           ->paginate(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by just changing the name **attribute** of **name = "query" to name = "q".**

I don't know what the problem was with name = "query" else everything is same .

So i would suggest you to don't use **'%'.$userInput.'%'** i tried this but it gives me nothing as a searching result into my view.

if i use  "%".$userInput."%" into with where clause  and changed the name attribute all works fine for me :)